# Android: Sharing (something) via Intent.ACTION_SEND, then automatically return to my app

Tags: android, action, send, sharing

I would like to share something from my application.
Once it is shared (e.g - message sent), I want my application to be active again and the sending app to disappear.
Using the code below, I expected `onActivityResult` to be called, but it is never called.

After sending email, my application appears again, but after sending SMS ('Messaging') the messaging app remains. (`onActivityResult` is never called)

Thanks :-)

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
String shareBody = "This is a test";
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "You have to see this!");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"),1);

getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will only be called if the user presses the back button. Because you are starting a new intent, so you give control to another application.
So normally, if the user presses the back button (which I would do as an Android user) the user will go back to your app. This the way I would prefer to use for this case, and as far as I know it is also the only way to do this in Android.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that if a user using an app which allows him to share something (like a URL), there's no reason to 'stay' on the messaging app after sharing. They expect to get back to their previous activity immediately after 'sharing'. Also, strange that 'email' and 'messaging' have completely different behavior.

Comment: @JRun: The decision of what happens as part of an `ACTION_SEND` operation is up to the other app (and the user), not you. `ACTION_SEND` is not designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`, which is why you are not getting results, and `startActivityForResult()` has no bearing on the behavior of the other app.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. Not the answer I was hoping for, but I guess that's what I have to work with.