# Is there any onActivityResult or response for shareIntent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an application where I can share a link to the applications available in the android devices and increase the share count but I am unable to get any **response** or **onActivityResult** for that **intent**.

For now I have just increased the counter when ever the button is clicked for sharing the link but that's not a correct way to do it.

I am using the below code to share the link

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\n" + text + "\n\n" + "www.google.com");
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Link using ?"));
```

Any help is appreciable thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) in [@ndsmyter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12708611/4848308) comments

> The decision of what happens as part of an ACTION_SEND operation is up
>   to the other app (and the user), not you. ACTION_SEND is not designed
>   for use with startActivityForResult(), which is why you are not
>   getting results, and startActivityForResult() has no bearing on the
>   behavior of the other app.

So as you see, is not possible :(

Hope this helps!!